# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' - Android

Tags: android

I've got a problem with my gradle scriptsi. 
I'm getting:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Here are my gradles:

Gradle (APP):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dbrewardsnew"
        minSdkVersion 15
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("kluczglowny.jks")
            storePassword "asiunia"
            keyAlias "android"
            keyPassword "asiunia"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'


    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'


    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'


    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.febaisi:custom-textview:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.scopely:fontain:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

}
```

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

And my settings gradle:

```
include ':app', ':googleplayserviceslib', ':unity-ads', ':calligraphy-2.2.0', ':pugnotification-1.8.1'
include ':appGradeLib'
```

Where is a problem? I don't see duplicate gms.

Comment: please remove or comment this line `compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')`  and sync again

Comment: @Shailesh now, im getting a lot of error with Google Api

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependencies depends on an older version of Google play services (the "monolithic" one: googleplayserviceslib). You cannot combine this version with a newer version.  Either only use the old version and not the newer google-play-services-auth, or remove/update what depends on the old version so it is compatible with newer google-play-services.

Post your build errors after removing one or removing the other for more help.

Comment: When I comment this folder I've got error like:
Error:(49, 35) error: package com.google.android.gms.plus does not exist

Comment: do you know which library made you add `compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')` to your build.gradle?

Comment: there are files for GCM

Comment: You'll need to add the individual google-play-services libraries needed as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

In this case `google-play-services-plus` and whatever else you get package does not exist errors for.